Android Placesclient getting garbage collection error
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(this.requireActivity(), BuildConfig.MAP_API_KEY)
    }

    placesClient = Places.createClient(requireActivity())

}

*\~*\~*\~ Previous channel {0} was garbage collected without being shut down! \~*\~*\~* Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzbme.\<init\>(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@3.5.0:3) at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzbmf.\<init\>(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@3.5.0:2) at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzbmd.zza(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@3.5.0:18) at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzazt.zza(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@3.5.0:1) at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzjn.zza(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@3.5.0:26) at com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places.zza(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@3.5.0:7) at com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places.createClient(com.google.android.libraries.places:places@@3.5.0:3) at com.FragmentMapLocation.onCreate(FragmentChargerMapLocation.kt:71) at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3094) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:504) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:268) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1943) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1845) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1782) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:565) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8674) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:886)
I used below code but even after making null getting same error
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
     placesClient = null
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    // Shut down the PlacesClient
         try {
             (placesClient as? AutoCloseable)?.close()
         } catch (e: Exception) {
             e.printStackTrace()
         }
}

